# jQuery autocomplete should skip disabled element when using keyboard

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, jquery-ui-autocomplete

If you see this [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m6zvf/5/), not done by me, how can I then avoid that the keyboard can go down and choose the disabled element? The mouse is working fine (not being able to select it) but I can go down with the keyboard and select it, resulting in an empty search :-/

The Fiddle demo is from this post, [How to disable element in jQuery autocomplete list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458374/how-to-disable-element-in-jquery-autocomplete-list)

jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"];

$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    response: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.content.length > 3) {
            while (ui.content.length > 3) {
                ui.content.pop();
            }
            ui.content.push({
                'label': 'Please narrow down your search',
                    'value': ''
            });
        }
    }
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li " + (item.value == '' ? 'class="ui-state-disabled"' : '') + ">")
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
});
```

Comment: I also have the same problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autocomplete "knows" to highlight items based on the presense of an `<a>` inside each `li`. You can disable keyboard selection of an event by just removing the anchor:

```
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        var $el = $("<li>");
        if (item.value === '') {
            $el.addClass("ui-state-disabled")
               .text(item.label);

        } else {
            $el.append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>");
        }

        return $el.appendTo(ul);
    };
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/m6zvf/12/

Comment: Why write var `$el = $("<li>")` and not just `var el = $("<li>")`? Is the $-sign an old habbit from other coding language or is it required elsewhere in jQuery?

Comment: It's a convention that you can use if you want to designate that a variable contains a jQuery object. It's just convention, not required. See this [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign) for more info.

Comment: This no longer seems to work with the new jQuery UI (1.11). Would love to see a solution for that.

Comment: @ragulka: I don't have time to come up with an example now, but  the "categories" example here http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories has an example of items in the list that cannot be selected.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: thanks, that's a good start - it seems that it's only a matter of using a different class for the non-selectable items.

Comment: @ragulka surely this is a bug in jQuery UI 1.11?  Having to explicitly set `this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-state-disabled)");` seems odd to me.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to Andrews answer, if you want to preserve the down key wrapping the focus to the first item, you can use the focus event to trigger a mouseenter on the first item upon the unfocusable item coming into focus.

Just add the code below as a focus property

[WORKING JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m6zvf/15/)

```
    focus: function(event, ui){
        var curr = $(event.currentTarget).find('a.ui-state-focus');
        if(curr.parent().hasClass('ui-state-disabled'))
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            curr.parent().siblings().first().children('a').mouseenter();  
        }
    }
```

Comment: mouseenter dos not put value into an input so I trigger keydown:
            focus : function(event, ui) {
              if (ui.item === '') {
                event.preventDefault();
                // skip first item and select second one
                var secondItem = $(event.currentTarget).children().eq(1);
                var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
                e.keyCode = 40;
                secondItem.trigger(e);
              }
            }