# How to disable click when autocomplete Field "no rseult found" via ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, laravel-5

I have done almost everything and I have successfully implemented autocomplete searching with ajax. Now problem is that when no data is found in autocomplete searching by default it shows No Result found. When I click on "NO Results Found" it is appearing on textbox. I want when No Results Found  and user tries to click on that it should be no clickable

[image]

[image]

Here is My jquery Code:

```
src = "{{ route('searchajax') }}";
$("#search_text").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: src,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term : request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    min_length: 3,
});
```

And My laravel 5.2 function

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request) {
    $query = $request->get('term','');

    $states=DB::table('states')->where('state','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->get();

    $data=array();
    foreach ($states as $state) {
            $data[]=array('value'=>$state->state,'id'=>$state->id);
    }
    if(count($data))
         return $data;
    else
        return ['value'=>'No Result Found','id'=>''];
}
```

Comment: What happens if you console.log `data` in your success function? You should be able to make a simple condition when id is empty.

Comment: Object { value: "No Result Found", id: "" }

Comment: yes we can check with id if is empty but how to disable the click on when user try to click on  "No Result Found"

Comment: It looks like you're doing it the wrong way. You should just check if `data` is empty and then display "No results found" in a custom div which is not clickable. Which means your PHP function should return an empty array instead of a "No results found" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458374/how-to-disable-element-in-jquery-autocomplete-list) is the answer you are looking for

You can use the `response` function to check if you do have results. If not, just push "No results found" to your list and then use `_renderItem` to disable this option.

```
$("#search_text").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: src,
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        term : request.term
      },
      success: function(data) {
        response(data);
      }
    });
  },
  min_length: 3,
  response: function(event, ui) {
    if( ui.content.length === 0 ) {
      ui.content.push({
        'label': 'No results found',
        'value': ''
      });
    }
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
  if( item.value == '' ) {
    return $('<li class="ui-state-disabled">'+item.label+'</li>').appendTo(ul);
  } else {
    return $("<li>").append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
  }
};
```

I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o86ny49j/1/) so you can see it working.